# Android AXML Layout Inconsistantcies -

Tags: android, layout

I'm working on an android product and I've set up my axml layout as I would like it to appear - however when using it on smaller or larger devices they do not appear as I would like them to due to different pixel density.

My question is: Is there a way to make a layout that looks appropriate without testing the layout for every single device and then making a new values sheet for each device? Considering there's a list of 30+ devices this seems like a large task that could be done arithmetically based on some sort of calculation in screen size differences.

Comment: "my axml layout" -- what is an "axml layout"? "when using it on smaller or larger devices they do not appear as I would like them to due to different pixel density" -- pixel density is independent of screen size. Beyond that, you need to provide [a minimal, complete, and verifiable example (MVCE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including a description of what "as I would like them" means (perhaps involving screenshots). "Is there a way to make a layout that looks appropriate" -- that depends a *lot* on what sort of UI structure you are trying to create, which is why we need the MVCE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend checking out Google's advice on "Supporting Multiple Screens", particularly the "How to Support Multiple Screens" section.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#support

Comment: Roger that. That's what I was afraid of to be honest. I was hoping I could write some java to take care of it. But from the looks of it I do not have to have more than four different layouts. I was worried I would have to have one layout per device. Thanks, Brother. I will select as answer when the time-limit passes.